# What do the pressure plates at the Sky Haven Temple entrance do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There are 5 pressure plates at the entrance to Sky Haven Temple. What do they do? When I step on them nothing seems to happen.

[image: pressure plates]
[image: pressure plates location]

Answer (score 9):

They don't appear to be interactable like other pressure plates in the game. Google searching points to similar sparse questions with no answers. Looking at the related quests and information from the wiki, there's nothing mentioning these either.

Since these have no importance and aren't linked to anything, these were most likely left over from unfinished content. It's possible that they were *planned* to be important, but was scrapped due to time constraints or several other possible factors.